# Mirroring Range of Cells in Between Sheets

Tags: excel, vba, range, cell

Sheet1

```
  Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B93")) Is Nothing Then
       If Target = Range("B93") Then
          Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = Target.Value
       End If
    End If
    
    End Sub
```

Sheet2

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
  If Target = Range("A1") Then
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B93").Value <> Target.Value Then
      Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B93").Value = Target.Value
    End If
  End If
End If

End Sub
```

The code works for only single cell on B93 and A1.

I tried setting the range to Range("B93:N122") on sheet1 and Range("A1:M22") on sheet 2 to mirror the ranges when changes happened but I get the error 13 mismatch.

Goal: I want to mirror the changes (two way) on range(A1:M22) sheet 1 to sheet 2 vice versa. What line of code am i missing?

Comment: OK sorry if I was unclear. OK let's say my range in sheet 1 is from A1:D6 then sheet 2 is A1:D6. I want to mirror the changes for example. I type yes on A1,B1 on sheet1, that should reflect on sheet2 and if I type no on B2,C2 sheet 2 that should reflect on sheet1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Mirror Ranges

- Values changed in cells of one worksheet will also change to the same values in the same cells of the other worksheet and vice versa.

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```
Option Explicit

Sub MirrorWorksheets( _
        ByVal Target As Range, _
        ByVal RangeAddress As String, _
        ByVal WorksheetName As String)
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = Target.Worksheet
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(sws.Range(RangeAddress), Target)
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = sws.Parent.Worksheets(WorksheetName) 
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim iarg As Range

    For Each iarg In irg.Areas
        dws.Range(iarg.Address).Value = iarg.Value
    Next iarg

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub
```

**`Sheet1` Module**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    MirrorWorksheets Target, "A1:M22,B93:N122", "Sheet2"
End Sub
```

**`Sheet2` Module**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    MirrorWorksheets Target, "A1:M22,B93:N122", "Sheet1"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this but somehow it doesn't work. I put the code standard module on module folder and the sheet1module on the sheet itself where the object directory is. I tested it by typing anything on one of the cells included on the range.

I tested it again on a new sheet and it works! I will just move on from here. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: You may have switched the sheet modules: not that in **Sheet1** is the code that contains `..."A1:M22,B93:N122", "Sheet2"` and vice versa. Also, when playing around with events, you may have accidentally disabled them. In a sub use the line `Application.EnableEvents = True` to enable them again.